# Relationship Diagram software

Tags: network-structure

I have some datasets that I would like to present in graphic form, as relationship diagram (see picture)

[image: On the left, written relation; on the right the graphic form I would like]

Do you know a software that can convert excel data in a such type of graph?

Comment: Questions like these have been asked in several forms on [softwarerecs.se]; try searching there for [graphs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+graphs), [relationship](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+relationship) or maybe [visualization](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+visualization). This is also a hint that software requests are better asked there ;-)

Answer (score 3):

mermaid just popped up in my github feed, looks to do just this:
[mermaid](http://knsv.github.io/mermaid/)
[repo](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid)